# Refresh updated data in MVC partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view that allows me to retrieve and edit data from a database using a strongly typed view.

My model:

```
  public partial class Associate
{
    public Associate()

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
....
```

and

```
public Associate GetRow(int count)
    {
        Associate a = new Associate();
        var query = from rows in db.Associates orderby rows.ID select rows;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var row in query.Skip(count - 1).Take(1))
            {
                a = row;
            }
            return a;
        }
....
```

My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult GetRow(int count)
    {
        return PartialView("Edit", new MVC.Models.Associate().GetRow(count));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Associate associate)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(associate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView("Edit",associate);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("../Error");
    }
```

My Index view:

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#record').change(function () {
    if (/^[0-9]+$/.test($("#record").val()) == true) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Associate/GetRow",
            data: { count: $('#record').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#FormContainer').html(data)
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
})  
   });
   </script>

<div id="FormContainer">
</div>
<input type=text id="record" style="width:3em; top:-0.7em;position:relative" />
```

and my Partial View:

```
  @model MVC.Models.Associate


 <script type="text/javascript" >
.....
 var form = $('#form1');
                $.ajax({
                    type: form.attr('method'),
                    url: form.attr('action'),
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert(result.responseText);
                    }
                });
....
</script>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Associate", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Contacts</legend>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ID)
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LatName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
.....
```

When I enter a new value into the #record input on the index form the Associates/GetRow returns the correct associate - this is working. The ajax function to update the record is called when the form loses the focus(code not shown). When I edit a field on the form and move the focus the underlying data in the database is changed to the new value - so both retrieving records and updating records is working.

However when I edit one record then move to the next record and then back to the edited record the updated values in the edited record are not shown. So the Associates/GetRow action returns the old values rather than getting the new values from the database. Or if I edit a field then manually or by code refresh the entire page or the partial view the new value is replaced with the old value even though the new value is stored in the underlying database.

I've tried 
        [OutputCache(Duration=0)] in my controller with no success.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

UPDATE 1:

The response headers are:

server: asp.net development server/10.0.0.0

date: sun, 08 sep 2013 19:21:16 gmt

x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319

x-aspnetmvc-version: 3.0

cache-control: private

content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

content-length: 2910

connection: close

If I close the browser window and clear cached web pages including form input and even Ctrl and F5 on my project to rebuild the web page the old data is still shown.  The only way I have found to show the new data is to make a change to the project and save the change then rebuild the project. Then the new data is shown.

UPDATE 2:

I have found another way to display the new data which might show what's going on. I have changed my Index View to include:

```
 <div id="FormContainer">
 @Html.Partial("Edit", new MVC.Models.Associate().GetRow(1))
 </div>
```

and then edit the first record.
When I edit the first record then move to a new record and back using the #record input the old values are still displayed. However if I manually refresh the page the new values are now displayed for the first record.

When I include the code you suggested in the GetRow function the new values are not displayed even if I refresh the page with the changes to the index view above.

UPDATE 3:

I've changed my index view as shown:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Button1').click(function(){
        RefreshPartial();
    })
 });

  function RefreshPartial() {
    $('#FormContainer').load('/Associate/GetRow', {count:1});    
  }
</script>
 <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
 <div id="FormContainer">
  @Html.Partial("Edit",new MVC.Models.Associate().GetRow(1))
 </div>
```

so now I have two alternative ways to get the first record.

If I edit a field in the record then click the button the RefreshPartial function runs and the new value is replaced with the old value. If I then refresh the page so the @Html.Partial code runs the old value is replaced with the new value. If I close the browser and reopen it the old value is displayed in all circumstances.

All the time the value in the underlying database is the new value.

UPDATE 4

As PaulD'Ambra pointed out below, my GetRow should have been getting an item from the model rather than being part of the model.  This is the GetRow controller action that works to retrieve the record from the database:

```
 public ActionResult GetRow(int count)
    {
        Associate a = new Associate();
        var query = from rows in db.Associates orderby rows.ID select rows;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var row in query.Skip(count - 1).Take(1))
            {
                a = row;
                a.record_count = count;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var row in query.Skip(query.Count() + 1).Take(1))
            {
                a = row;
                a.record_count = count;
            }
        }
        return PartialView("Edit", a);
    }
```

Comment: It sounds very much like the browser is serving the page from its local cache so I think you're on the right path with OutputCache. What are the response headers when you load the page?

Comment: @PaulD'Ambra Hi Paul please see my update above.

Comment: So, there's nothing in the headers that would stop the client caching the page... but it updates if you change a value... weird

Comment: It's unusual to have the dbContext in the model... and I'm struggling to grok what will happen with the caching and proxying EF will do to instances of the model. Normally, your controller would have the dbContext (or some type that wraps it) and each call to GetRow in the controller would call out to the dbContext for the item with that model...

Comment: Thank you Paul that was the problem. I've moved the GetRow functionality into my controller, changed the index view back to the original and it seems to be working fine. I'm trying to learn to use MVC and I've been struggling from the start with what goes in the model and what goes in the controller. No dbContext in the model is obviously a good rule. I've put my updated controller above as Update 4 if anyone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `ModelState.Clear()` in your Edit method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Associate associate)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a caching problem you could identify this by adding (for the sake of identifying the issue)

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false)
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches)
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
```

into your GetRow method.

This tells the client not to cache the response so you can rule that out (and you'll be able to see the impact of these changes in the response headers).

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this.  Please see my second update above.
These are the changes to my response headers:
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

pragma: no-cache

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = "@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")))";
            $("#PartialViewDivId").load(url);
        setInterval(function () {
            var url = "@(Html.Raw(Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")))";
            $("#PartialViewDivId").load(url);
        }, 30000); //Refreshes every 30 seconds

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });  //Turn off caching
    });
```

It makes an initial call to load the div, and then subsequent calls are on a 30 second interval.

In the controller section you can update the object and pass the object to the partial view.

```
public class ControllerName: Controller
{
    public ActionResult ActionName()
    {
        .
        .   // code for update object
        .
        return PartialView("PartialViewName", updatedObject);
    }
}
```